# How to skip ALL Callbacks while creating/updating an ActiveRecord in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, callback

I need a simple way to skip validations and callbacks while updating an active record.

I am running the following code:

```
Student.find_or_create_by(id: data['id']).update(data)
```

where `data` is the hash having keys same as columns in students.
It works as expected. But I want to avoid all callbacks and validations while updating. As mentioned in some of the stack overflow answers, I tried:

```
Student.find_or_create_by(id: data['id']).send(:update_without_callbacks, data)
```

It doesn't work, says undefined method `update_without_callbacks`.

Isn't there any simple straightforward method like `update_by_skipping_callbacks` or `update(skip_callbacks: true, data)` in Rails?

Answer (score 3):

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks

you can try `update_columns` method

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns

Just keep in mind that this goes straight to the database, so `updated_at` column is not updated unless you update it explicitly

Comment: find_or_create may create a new record, in which update_columns fails giving  ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Student.find_or_create_by(id: data['id']).assign_attributes(data).save(validate: false)
```

Comment: It'll skip validations but what about callbacks?

Comment: If you need to skip callbacks as well then use `update_columns` but I am not a fan of callbacks and therefore I would strongly suggest not using callbacks because ... they are pure evil...